# Arduino Obstacle Avoidance (Problem)

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics

I am having a problem. I designed obstacle robot with ultrasonic sensor. But the problem i'm facing is one that no one discussed ever. I kept on searching it on internet and found no solution for it. So, i decided to ask it here:

Firstly, I used one ultrasonic sensor to avoid obstacle alongwith servo motor using **newping** library. But it failed badly due to an elevation of the sensor so it doesn't detect any lower height object.

Second time, i used three ultrasonic sensors to check for the side's obstacles and front obstacle as well. In most of the cases what no one ever showed in video there are some places and times when it get stuck (due to design and even sonar limitation).

What i want to do is to add some features to the code that can detect stuck motor or stopped robot at one place. Once detected this condition it moves backward and turn the other way if again stuck then move backward and turn the other way.

I hope i could make you understand the problem i'm facing. I'll appreciate the solution and it may help others to find solution for it. I don't know how to attach the code here (it may create mess for the reader). So, please tell me if i need to send or attach here. Thanks.!

Comment: you could add bump sensors(switches) so that it it bumps into an object, it can back up and turn the right way(depending on which sensor is hit).   Think about humans, how do we get around if we cant see?

Comment: hint: a robot will get stuck in some places because it always reacts the same way to a particular sensor input